# How to remove the extra space as a result of double quotes in SAS

Tags: perl, sas, batch-processing

I am new to SAS and I am trying create a batch file through a SAS program. The code is below:

```
data new;
enddate=date();
getdate=date()+1;
flname1=compress("d:\temp\file"||year(enddate)||put(month(enddate),z2.)||
   put(day(enddate),z2.)||".txt");
begdate=enddate-&days;
dtline1=compbl(compress("00:00_"||put(begdate,mmddyy10.))||" "||
compress("00:00_"||put(getdate,mmddyy10.)));
file 'h:\programs\daily_file';
put 'LOGIN abc xyz';
put 'FILE(C:\temp\list.txt) 
dtline1 "script.pl("flname1")";
put 'LOGOUT';
```

Script.pl is a perl script and in the resulting batch file, there is an extra space after `flname1`. It prints something like this:

> script.pl(d:\temp\file_date ).

I don't want the this extra space after date. What can I do?

Comment: @darkfang That's a pretty bad edit there.  Please pay more attention when suggesting edits - in particular, you're reverting from a correct tag edit to an incorrect tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to get that to work properly is simply to put the entire command (`script.pl(filename)`) into a single variable, then put that variable.

You can also use +(-1) in put to move the line pointer back one, if it's consistently off by one (though most of the time that's not needed).

```
put "script.pl(" flname1 +(-1) ")";
```

Comment: Joe-Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help. +(-1) thing worked and my batch file is running perfect. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like you are working too hard to create string variables before writing to the file.  You should be able to write what you want just using the features of the PUT statement.  It is not clear from the question what format you want the file to have, but I think this code mimics your program.

```
%let days=7 ;
data new;
  enddate=date();
  getdate=date()+1;
  begdate=enddate-&days;
  file 'h:\programs\daily_file';
  put 'LOGIN abc xyz'
    / 'FILE(C:\temp\list.txt) 00:00_' begdate mmddyy10. 
      ' 00:00_' getdate mmddyy10. 
      ' script.pl(d:\temp\file' enddate yymmddn8. '.txt)'
    / 'LOGOUT'
  ;
run;
```

and it produces:

```
LOGIN abc xyz
FILE(C:\temp\list.txt) 00:00_08/14/2015 00:00_08/22/2015 script.pl(d:\temp\file20150821.txt)
LOGOUT
```